# Configure the http client of httpbuilder ng to not follow 302 redirects

Tags: http, redirect, groovy, httpbuilder-ng

I try to write some regression tests for my web application with Groovy and `http-builder-ng`.
To check all the headers for every request I would like to turn off
the auto redirection. To do this with `http-builder` there are `BasicHttpParams`, but I think `BasicHttpParams` are not working with `http-builder-ng`.
Is there another way to turn off auto redirection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't use `http-builder-ng` before, but from the docs I don't see a way to configure this directly. But you use some variant with client implementation, by default `core`, `apache` or `okhttp`. I guess you need to configure the underlying client library you are using to not follow redirects using `clientCustomizer` as described at https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/asciidoc/html5/#_client.

E. g. with the `core` variant:

```
http = configure {
    request.uri = 'test.com'
    client.clientCustomizer { it.followRedirects = false }
}
```